# Implement replacement for "terraform.ReadPlan is no longer in use"

Tags: terraform

Microsoft provides an example for testing Terraform infrastructure using Terratest:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/terraform/terratest-in-terraform-modules
There is an interesting part of code:

```
        // Terraform init and plan only
        tfPlanOutput := "terraform.tfplan"
        terraform.Init(t, tfOptions)
        terraform.RunTerraformCommand(t, tfOptions, terraform.FormatArgs(tfOptions.Vars, "plan", "-out="+tfPlanOutput)...)

        // Read and parse the plan output
        f, err := os.Open(path.Join(tfOptions.TerraformDir, tfPlanOutput))
        if err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer f.Close()
        plan, err := terraformCore.ReadPlan(f)
```

If you try to execute it on Terraform 0.12, you get error:

```
terraform.ReadPlan is no longer in use; use planfile.Open instead
```

The question is, how can I reimplement Microsoft's code to work with Terraform 0.12? How can I convert ***File** into **Plan**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message is aimed at people working on the Terraform codebase itself, rather than external callers. The `terraform` Go package is not a public API and so while it is technically *possible* for other Go codebases to call into it, there are no compatibility promises for it and any other systems calling into it are likely to be broken (as we see in this case) by refactoring in future releases.

With that said, Terraform 0.12 introduced a supported way to decode a saved plan file for inspection in other software, via [`terraform show -json <planfile>`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/show.html#json-output).

`terratest` has a function [`RunTerraformCommandAndGetStdoutE`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/terraform#RunTerraformCommandAndGetStdoutE) which you could use to run `terraform show -json <planfile>` and get the raw JSON output:

```
planJSON, err := terraform.RunTerraformCommandAndGetStdoutE(
    t, tfOptions, terraform.FormatArgs("show", "-json", tfPlanOutput)...
)
```

Then you can use the Go standard library `encoding/json` package to parse it into some `struct` types of your own that cover the subset of [the JSON output format](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/json-format.html#plan-representation) you need for the tests you intend to write.

Comment: Your solution is very smart! Thanks! <br/>
However, I had to add minor modifcation as FormatArgs requires *Options as 1st parameter:
```
func FormatArgs(options *Options, args ...string)
```
So my final solution is:
```
tfOptionsEmpty := &terraform.Options{
} 

planJSON, err := terraform.RunTerraformCommandAndGetStdoutE(t, tfOptions, terraform.FormatArgs(tfOptionsEmpty, "show", "-json", tfPlanOutput)...)
```

Comment: Beware: RunTerraformCommandAndGetStdoutE will pass in any Vars you define in TerraformOptions